# Monthly payments not updating for monthly direct debit

Tags: civimember, import, contribution-page, recurring-contributions

We have a number of members who pay in monthly instalments by direct debit, but recently the contribution page and the membership end date have not been updating. We have received the reports showing that payment has been collected.

Is there any way to fix this?

I am using civi 5.10.3 and SmartDebit version 1.30 (Thank you for showing where to find this, Craig).

Comment: What version of the smartdebit extension?

Comment: How do I find out which version of SmartDebit I am using?

Comment: Navigating through to [yoursite]/civicrm/admin/extensions?reset=1 will show all installed extensions with version number. Normally under Administer>SystemSettings